# Implement navigation properties in OrmLite (ServiceStack)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ormlite-servicestack

I want to have the EF kind of navigation properties for OrmLite. Is there any resource to explain how EF implements navigation properties ? I know that it requires those fields to be virtual, but I would like to learn how it loads the actually data under the hood in order to have the same for OrmLite.

Comment: EF6 is [open source](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/). I don't think there is any specific technical documentation on lazy loading.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, I thought about that, but still the code base is huge I will need some guidance on where to dig.

Comment: To implement navigation properties you need them to be virtual and use Dynamic Proxy to create subclass instances on the fly.